# Using @ for imports in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

I am trying to get my declarations to work using `@`

```
import Component from '@/components/test.vue';
```

But what I get is cannot find declaration. The `src` folder is marked as Resource root.

I hope that this description is enough that someone can understand my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which module loader/bundler you are using? `@` isn't part of JavaScript perasy...I think you are probably missing a babel plugin?

Comment: For reference purposes, the same on JetBrains forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007839760-PHPstorm-using-for-path-declaration-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to specify `path/to/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js` as a value of  **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack, webpack configuration file** and re-open the project

[image]